I'd like the order of my hash table be the order I added the items
Given:
PowerShell 5.1
I would have thought since hashtables aren't ordered by default, it would be in the order I added it?
What gives? lol
I would like it to be in the order I added the items if possible.
$rshash = @{}
$rshash += @{ "test"=1 }
$rshash += @{ "apple"="m" }
$rshash += @{ "map"="d" }

$rshash

Result:
Name                           Value                                                                              
----                           -----                                                                              
apple                          m                                                                                  
map                            d                                                                                  
test                           1 


Use an ordered dictionary instead. $rshash = [ordered]@{}

@SantiagoSquarzon - Elaborate on that a little and propose it as an answer rather than a comment.

@JeffZeitlin elaborate on what? this has been answered hundreds of times before. I found a duplicate in less than a minute to put it into perspective.

@SantiagoSquarzon - yeah, sorry about that - I missed seeing that it was a dupe when I pulled up the question.

Thanks, post that answer for credit
